# How do I instantiate bean properties in Jakarta Faces for future pages?

Tags: jsf, master-detail

I am using Jakarta Faces 9.1 (Glassfish 7/TomEE).  I have a page which, given a valid entry (bean.in1/UIInput), is used to generate text for a subsequent page entry (bean.in2/UIInput) which a user can then edit.  When in1 and in2 are on the same page there is no problem.  When in2 is on a subsequent page, I get "this.in2 is null" errors on the update() method.

I worked around this with a "rendered=false" (ie: hidden) for bean.in2/UIInput on the first page and a "rendered=true" for bean.in2/UIInput on the second subsequent page (as otherwise it would not show).  I tried <f:view beforePhase="..." /> which prevents null errors but in2 is not updated in the subsequent page.  The following minimal code shows the idea.  The bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    private UIInput in1;
    private UIInput in2;
    
    public void update() {
        // in1 is processed to produce in2 values:
        in2.setValue("Yo!!");
    }

    public UIInput getIn1() { return in1; }
    public void setIn1(UIInput in1) { this.in1 = in1; }

    public UIInput getIn2() { return in2; }
    public void setIn2(UIInput in2) { this.in2 = in2; }
}
```

The pages:

```
    <h:body>
        <div>Bakedbean testing</div>
        <h:form id="form0">
            <h:outputLabel for="rltd" value="Arbitrary input" />
            <h:inputText id="rltd"
                         binding="#{bean1.in1}"
                         valueChangeListener="#{bean1.update}"
                         immediate="true"
                         required="true">
            </h:inputText>
            <!-- This prevents in2 null errors -->
            <h:inputText id="in2" binding="#{bean1.in2}" rendered="false" />
        </h:form>
        <h:button id="next" value="Next" outcome="/next.xhtml" />
    </h:body>

    <h:body>
        <div>Next</div>
        <h:form id="next2">
            <h:outputLabel for="related">in2 instantiated?</h:outputLabel>
            <!-- This requires rendered as true because in2 is rendered as false on prev. page -->
            <p><h:inputTextarea id="related" style="border: 1px solid red;" rows="2" cols="25" rendered="true" binding="#{bean1.in2}"></h:inputTextarea></p>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

This seems pretty hokey to me.  Is there a way to instantiate in2 (even to "", avoiding null errors) as I believe managed-beans in faces-config in earlier versions used to allow?  I have not found anything in Jakarta CDI documentation that gives me a clue.

UPDATE:
I *may* have solved this by creating two beans where Bean1 is RequestScoped (and backs the 1st page) but also injects Bean2 which is SessionScoped and backs the 2nd page. Both beans use String instead of UIInput. Bean2 then updates the 2nd page inputTextArea value via a call in Bean1 (not binding).  This obviates the hidden/rendered=true stuff. I'm hoping this solution does not run into memory or concurrency problems hence why I'm not adding this as a full answer.

Comment: I don't know exactly, because wtf, but why are you storing `UIInput` in beans? Bean properties in JSF are just supposed to be pojos but you are trying to store JSF lifecycle stuff in the bean. Doesn't make sense. Change your thinking.

Comment: UIInput is the contents of the web page field.  If I make in1/in2 Strings I get class cast exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'd already tried RequestScoped (as is strongly suggested) but despite update() being called, in2 is never updated on the page whether I use String or UIInput to declare in2.  I might have to implement the "train wreck" code that BalusC outlined.

Comment: Don't know, but as suggested, keeping information in a bean in a session in JSF should be pretty easy since that it what it was designed to do. I saw some suggestions about injecting managed session beans into requestscoped beans for some reason but didn't look too closely at that. If you're going to work with JSF you will probably need to play around a bit until you get the hang of it. The life cycle of the page nav and rendering is bothersome. IMHO JSF looked much better on paper than in real life.

Comment: @K.Nicholas: *"BalusC wrote most of JSF impl"* This is not true. I was only involved since 2.3. Look up commit histories.